# Actualizar objeto en lista genérica .NET

Tags: c#, net

Con este código entenderéis a lo que me refiero, funciona correctamente:

```
private static readonly List<Product> products = new();

public Task<bool> UpdateAsync(Product product)
{
    var existingProduct = products.FirstOrDefault(p => product != null && p.Id == product.Id);
    if (existingProduct == null)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }

    existingProduct.Name = product.Name;

    existingProduct.IsInStock = product.IsInStock;
    existingProduct.Price = product.Price;
    existingProduct.Category = product.Category;
    existingProduct.ImageFileName = product.ImageFileName;
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Cuando cambiamos las propiedades del objeto que nos devolvió `FirstOrDefault()` no se hace necesario remover el objeto.
Por qué puedo cambiar las propiedades de un objeto contenido dentro de una lista genérica sin necesidad de removerlo anteriormente y añadirlo posteriormente? (.NET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen dos tipos de datos: **tipo de datos por valor** y **tipo de datos por referencia**. Los tipos de datos por valor almacenan un dato en concreto como puede ser un **int** o un **booleano**.

**Los tipos de datos por valor se almacenan en la pila**, estos se crean cuando se da entrada al procedimiento o bloque que contiene estas variables y se liberan automáticamente cuando se sale de este bloque.

**Los tipos de datos por referencia** apuntan a un espacio en memoria, estos **se almacenan en el heap**, lo que quiere decir que el espacio se asigna cuando es requerido, y cuando estos objetos ya no hacen falta deben ser destruidos, en **C#** el encargado de detectar y eliminar objetos que ya no se usan es el **recolector de basura**, ahorrándonos ese paso, pero en **C++** por ejemplo esa responsabilidad recae en el programador, por lo que hay que ser muy cuidadosos una vez que ese objeto es destruido, pues se borra de la memoria y ese espacio quedaría libre para ser usado por otro objeto.

Ahora bien, explicada esta teoría, te respondo tu ejemplo, cuando tu dices
**obj1 = obj2**, no estás asignando a **obj1** el valor de **obj2**, sino que le estás diciendo a **obj1** que apunte a la misma dirección de memoria de **obj2** por tanto al apuntar a la misma dirección ambos objetos digamos tendrán el mismo contenido, esto quiere decir que si cambias alguna propiedad de **obj1**, **obj2** tendrá el mismo cambio ya que ambos apuntan al mismo lugar en la memoria. Los **tipos de datos por referencia** son por ejemplo los objetos que son **instancias de una clase**, los **string**, etcétera.

En los **tipos de datos por valor** si asignas, ejemplo: cuando dices **num = num2**, le estás diciendo a **num** que tome el valor de **num2**, pero como ambos tienen sus propias direcciones de memoria, puedes cambiar el valor de **num**, que **num2** no se enterará ya que no apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria.

Comment: Un valor por referencia creado dentro del método, también es destruido al terminar el método, que serian mas que nada valores de Generacion 1, y son los primeros en ser destruidos. Un tipo por valor primitivo ocupa su propio lugar en la memoria y no hace falta ser clonado para no cambiar por error sus valores desde otra referencia. Podrias acompañarlos con codigo para que sea mas facil de entender.