# ¿Cómo funcionan las referencias en C#?

Tags: c#, referencias

que tal! soy nuevo en C# y ahora me topé con un tema que es sobre el uso de referencias.

Dado el siguiente código:

```
Tesis diss1 = new Tesis();
Tesis diss2 = diss1;
diss1.PaginaActual = 0;
diss2.PaginaActual = 16;
Console.WriteLine(diss1.PaginaActual);
Console.WriteLine(diss2.PaginaActual);

Dissertation diss = new Dissertation();
Book bdiss = diss;
IFlippable fdiss = diss;
```

Se menciona que `diss1` pasa a ser una variable de tipo `Tesis` o sea de la clase, pero no entiendo qué significa la línea: `Tesis diss2 = diss1;` ¿por qué no usar: `Tesis diss2 = new Tesis();` ? Y al compilar el código veo que me da de salida 16 en ambos llamados para imprimir, entonces, `diss2` ¿pasa a tener también todas las propiedades y métodos de `Tesis`?

Otra duda, respecto al código siguiente:

```
  Book b1 = new Book();
  Book b2 = new Diary();

  Console.WriteLine(b1.Stringify());
  Console.WriteLine(b2.Stringify());
```

Ese código abarca tema de polimorfismo, pero duda en la declaración de la segunda variable `b2`, qué signfica `new Diary();` ? porque cuando creo objetos en la parte del new, siempre coloco la misma clase a la que estoy haciendo el objeto como en `Book` pero en este ejemplo, se coloca otra clase.

Gracias y espero me puedan apoyar a resolver esas dudas y en que momentos podemos aplicar las referencias.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417538/actualizar-objeto-en-lista-gen%c3%a9rica-net/417557#417557 entra aqui

Comment: En el comentario que te pasaron esta la explicación, pero de manera mas corta, Referencia es una lugar en memoria, entonces diss1 y diss2 apuntan al mismo lugar, entonces cuando cambias un valor, también ese cambio se refleja en la otra variable. Tenes doc de sobra en Microsoft y esta en español.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Actualizar objeto en lista genérica .NET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417538/actualizar-objeto-en-lista-gen%c3%a9rica-net)