# ¿Cuato tiempo duran las variables en java?

Tags: java

```
Identificar el tiempo de vida de las variables al instanciar un objeto.
```

Soy nuevo en Java y por lo que tenia entendido las variables se usan en los programas y su tiempo de vida es hasta que se termina el programa, o al menos eso a sido lo que e investigado.
¿Oh esta mal ese concepto?

En este caso si no es así ¿Cuál es el tiempo de vida de las variables al instanciar un objeto?...

¿Es hasta que se termina el método?... Alguien me puede ayudar por favor explicándome esta duda.
De ante mano gracias

Comment: Estoy comenzando en POO, y estamos mirando en encapsulamiento pero... Yo opino que si es acerca de la clase ya que ahí se crea el objeto, ¿No es asi?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417538/actualizar-objeto-en-lista-gen%c3%a9rica-net/417557#417557, entra aquí, puede aclararte algunas dudas ya que hay una parte donde se explica lo que preguntas

Answer (score 3):

El tiempo de vida de todas las variables (entendemos por variable aquellas que se declaran dentro de un método) estará determinado por el *ámbito* (*scope* en inglés) donde se haya declarado. Una vez el flujo de ejecución del programa salga de dicho *ámbito* la variable será destruida.

```
// Ejemplo 1
void test() {
    int num = 0;
    System.out.println(num);
}// num dejará de existir al terminar la ejecución del método


// Ejemplo 2
void test(boolean) {
    if (ok) {
        int num = 0;
        System.out.println(num);
    }// num dejará de existir al salir del if
    
    System.out.println("Un texto cualquiera");
}
```

Ahora bien, una cosa es que la variable haya sido destrida (que no exista) y otra es que el dato que esta contenía también lo haya sido.

Si la variable es de tipo primitivo (`int`, `float`, `double`, `boolean`, etc.) su valor también será eliminado, o lo que es igual, la región de la memoria donde este se almacenaba será liberado y se podrá reutilizar. Si por el contrario el tipo de dato de la variable es una referencia (*reference type* en inglés) la memoria a la que apuntaba dicha variable solo será liberada por el recolector de basura si no existe otra variable (o atributo de un objeto) que tenga la misma referencia.

```
// Ejemplo 3
void test() {
    Person p = new Person("Pepe");
    System.out.println(p.getName());
}
/* p dejará de existir al terminar la ejecución del método y el valor del
   atributo `name` será eliminado eventualmente por el recolector de basura */


// Ejemplo 4
void test(Person p) {
    Person p2 = p;
    System.out.println(p2.getName());
}
/* p2 dejará de existir al terminar la ejecución del método pero el valor del
   atributo `name` NO será eliminado por el recolector de basura, puesto que
   todavía existe una referencia (la referencia que nos pasan con el parámetro
   p) a este. */
```

A los atributos de un objeto se le aplican las mismas reglas, pero el ámbito de estos es toda la clase, por lo que mientras exista el objeto estos perdurarán en el tiempo.

Se que puede ser un poco complicado, pero espero te ayude.

Comment: Si es un poco confuso, pero si logre entender ya un poco mejor acerca de esta situación. Muchas gracias

Comment: @Edy1999YT me alegra que te haya servido de ayuda :)